# Get distinct emails of users who commented on a ticket in Laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

I have the following models.

**Ticket**

```php
class Ticket extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'content', 'slug', 'status', 'user_id'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id', 'id');
    }

    public function commenters()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Comment');
    }
}
```

**Comment**

```php
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Ticket', 'post_id', 'id');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**User**

```php
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

- A ticket has many comments
- A comment has one user

I'm trying to extract a name-string list of users who commented on a ticket, but with no success.

In my controller, I'm using the following code to extract the list of commenters.

```php
Ticket::where('id', $comment->post_id)->commenters
```

However, I'm getting the error:

> Property [commenters] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closure. This query is unfinished:

```php
Ticket::where('id', $comment->post_id)
```

And an unfinished query is an instance of the `Builder` class, not a `Ticket` instance, or `Collection` of `Ticket` instances as you're expecting.

If you're expecting a single `Ticket` instance, then you'd use `->first()`:

```php
$ticket = Ticket::where('id', $comment->post_id)->with(['commenters'])->first();
$commenters = $ticket->commenters;
```

If you're expecting multiple `Ticket` instances, then you'd use `->get()`:

```php
$tickets = Ticket::where('id', $comment->post_id)->with(['commenters'])->get();
foreach($tickets AS $ticket){
  $commenters = $ticket->commenters;
}
```

Note: `->with(['commenters'])` is used to speed up the loading of `->commenters`; if you omit it, then a new query is run when you try to access `$ticket->commenters`.